# Dynamic dashboard

Tags: .net, winforms, graphics

I am looking for a .NET Winforms control (or suggestions on how best to code it myself) that does the following:

- Displays a map/layout of a client's premises (uploaded as an image).
- Overlays this image with icons representing sensors located at various locations on the premises. These icons will indicate the location and state of the sensor (green, red etc).
- The icons will need to change in real time to reflect the current state of the sensor.
- Allows the user to pan and zoom the whole control as it will be a large image and there is not going to be enough real estate to fit everything into one view.
- Allows the user to drag and drop icons onto the image and/or modify the layout.

Alternatively, if there are 3rd party applications that does this sort of thing out of the box then we're happy to spend the money and not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I think this control will get you half way through and then you will have to code the placement of the sensors yourself.

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsPictureEdittopic

the placement of sensors most probably you have to handle your self.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am the lead developer for VG.net. This tool is designed for your type of application. For example:
http://www.vgdotnet.com/process_control.shtml